# Selector not working with android recycleviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-selector

I am implementing a recycleview to display list of data. I want to highlight selected item on recycleview. It is working while clickable,focusable and focusableInTouchMode are true. But in that case item view click listner not working. Please help me on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bg_land"
app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/recycle_item_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//some stuff here

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is my selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item  android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_activated="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
<shape>
    <solid android:color="@color/bg_land" />
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Please provide the code what you are trying.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code ?

Comment: Ok, I have provided the code

Comment: RecyclerView does not have special provisions for attaching click handlers to items unlike ListView which has the method setOnItemClickListener(). To get a similar effect, we can attach click events within the ViewHolder within our adapter:

Comment: Yes, I did it similar way. But when I set clickable and focusable true on recycleview item for selector to work, itemview onClicklistner not working